# Getting Error while trying to upload image using CSV through data loader

Tags: apex, force.com, data-loader, csv, dataloader.io

**Below is the CSV -**
[image]

**Below is the Error -**
SOURCE: 'Body' DESTINATION: 'Body' ERROR:Body: value not of required type:

Comment: What kind of object are you trying to upload, a Document object?

Comment: From FolderId field, it seems it is document object. The format looks fine to me. So not sure of source of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Body needs to be a blob, not a string. You should handle conversion of that value in your code when you pass in the csv file for upload.

```
Blob.valueOf( 'your body column here' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The database record you're creating only holds the link to the document. The document itself is stored/saved as a 'blob' by salesforce in the database at the location that's specified. Uploading it using a CSV file doesn't allow that transformation to a blob to take place if you want Salesforce to store it locally. In your screen capture, you are showing the source location as being on your E drive. That's leaves it still on your drive, not within Salesforce and only creates a link to it.